# Convert log file to PCAP

Tags: wireshark, pcap

I have some log file that I want to convert to PCAP file format to be opened in Wireshark. The log file is UDS (Unified Diagnostic Services) log of a car firmware update. What is the best practice to do that?

The log file lines look like this:

```
***BUSMASTER Ver 3.2.1***
***PROTOCOL CAN***
***NOTE: PLEASE DO NOT EDIT THIS DOCUMENT***
***[START LOGGING SESSION]***
***START DATE AND TIME 4:6:2018 9:2:12:212***
***HEX***
***SYSTEM MODE***
***START CHANNEL BAUD RATE***
***CHANNEL 2 - Kvaser - Kvaser USBcan Pro 5xHS #0 (Channel 1), Serial Number- 0, Firmware- 0x0000013b 0x00030007 - 500000 bps***
***END CHANNEL BAUD RATE***
***START DATABASE FILES***
***END DATABASE FILES***
***<Time><Tx/Rx><Channel><CAN ID><Type><DLC><DataBytes>***
00:00:00:0000 Rx 2 0x064 s 8 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20
00:00:00:0574 Rx 2 0x7cd s 8 4d 72 2e 20 61 6e 64 20
00:00:00:0952 Rx 2 0x7df s 8 02 01 00 00 00 00 00 00
00:00:00:1457 Rx 2 0x05b s 8 ad dc 0b cc 0a c3 49 40
00:00:00:2069 Rx 2 0x05c s 8 63 d3 4a 21 90 4b c4 bf
00:00:00:2649 Rx 2 0x7cd s 8 4d 72 73 2e 20 44 75 72
```

Comment: The file format looks like this: https://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-gharris-opsawg-pcap-00.html

Comment: Selecting the right value for [LinkType](https://www.tcpdump.org/linktypes.html) is a bit of a puzzle. You can either try using a private value or you could pretend you are LINKTYPE_ETHERNET and prepend the captured frames with some made up ethernet headers.

Answer (score 0):

> I have some log file that I want to convert to PCAP file format to be opened in Wireshark. The log file is UDS (Unified Diagnostic Services) log of a car firmware update.

...

> ```
> ***BUSMASTER Ver 3.2.1***
> ```

...

> ```
> ***CHANNEL 2 - Kvaser - Kvaser USBcan ...
> ```

...

> ```
> ***<Time><Tx/Rx><Channel><CAN ID><Type><DLC><DataBytes>***
> ```

If you're using [Busmaster](https://rbei-etas.github.io/busmaster/), note that [Wireshark can read Busmaster log files](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChIOOpenSection.html#ChIOInputFormatsSection) - it is *not* limited to reading only pcap and pcapng files.  Try just opening that log file in Wireshark.

Answer (score -1):

1. Install tcpdump: PCAP files are generated using network sniffers, and tcpdump is
   a popular open-source packet analyzer that you can use for this purpose.
2. Convert logs to TCP stream: Use the following command to convert
   logs to a TCP stream:

```bash
$ awk '{print "192.168.1.1",$1,"192.168.1.2",$4,$5,$7}' access_log > http.req
```

This command will print the source IP address (192.168.1.1), HTTP method (GET or POST), destination IP address (192.168.1.2), response code, response size, and URL path from each log entry into the HTTP.req file.

3. Convert TCP stream to PCAP: Use tcpdump to capture the TCP stream and save it in PCAP format:

```bash
$ sudo tcpdump -nn -r http.req -w http.pcap
```

This command will capture the TCP stream from the `http.req` file and write it to the `http.pcap` file.

Comment: "sudo tcpdump -nn -r http.req -w http.pcap" will not work unless the "http.req" file is a pcap or pcapng file; it will not work on a plain text file.  (And "sudo" isn't necessary when reading from a file, unless you don't have permission to read the file.)